# STM32F407 SPI reciveing only 0xFF (255) or 0

Tags: c, motion-detection, stm32f4discovery

Recently I have been trying to receive a data from my STM32F407 motion sensor. I have the following code:

```
uint8_t SPI1_Read(){
 GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_4); // CS low
 while(SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1,SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE)==RESET){}
 SPI_I2S_SendData(SPI1, 0x00);
 while(SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE)==RESET){}
 return SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI1);
}

void SPI1_Write(uint8_t data){
 while(SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1,SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE)==RESET){}
 SPI_I2S_SendData(SPI1, data);
 while (SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE) == RESET){}
 SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI1);
}

volatile static int vrednost, vrednost1, vrednost2;

int main(void)
{
  // Vkljuci driver za GPIOD
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);

  // Nastavi registre za LED diode
  GPIO_InitTypeDef inicializacijskaStruktura;
  inicializacijskaStruktura.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
  inicializacijskaStruktura.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  inicializacijskaStruktura.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
  inicializacijskaStruktura.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
  inicializacijskaStruktura.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_12 | GPIO_Pin_13 | GPIO_Pin_14 | GPIO_Pin_15;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &inicializacijskaStruktura);

  SPI_and_GPIO_Init();

  // init
  SPI1_Write(0x20);
  SPI1_Write(0x47);
  SPI1_Write(0x0F);
  SPI1_Write(0xBC);

  while(1)
  {

    SPI1_Write(0x20);
    vrednost=SPI1_Read();

    SPI1_Write(0x24);
    vrednost1=SPI1_Read();

    SPI1_Write(0x28);
    vrednost2=SPI1_Read();

    if(vrednost<122){
      GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_12);

    }
    else{
      GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_12);

    }

    if(vrednost1<122)
      GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_13);
    else
      GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_13);

    if(vrednost2<122)
      GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_14);
    else
      GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_14);
  }
}






void SPI_and_GPIO_Init(){
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;


  /* Enable the SPI periph */
  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_SPI1, ENABLE);

  /* Enable SCK, MOSI and MISO GPIO clocks */
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA , ENABLE);

  /* Enable CS  GPIO clock */
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOE, ENABLE);


  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource5, GPIO_AF_SPI1);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource6, GPIO_AF_SPI1);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource7, GPIO_AF_SPI1);


  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd  = GPIO_PuPd_DOWN;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;

  /* SPI pins configuration */
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_5|GPIO_Pin_6|GPIO_Pin_7;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

/* SPI configuration -------------------------------------------------------*/
  SPI_I2S_DeInit(SPI1);
  SPI_InitTypeDef  SPI_InitStructure;     
  SPI_InitStructure.SPI_Direction = SPI_Direction_2Lines_FullDuplex;
  SPI_InitStructure.SPI_DataSize = SPI_DataSize_8b;
  SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_Low;
  SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_1Edge;
  SPI_InitStructure.SPI_NSS = SPI_NSS_Soft;
  SPI_InitStructure.SPI_BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_4;
  SPI_InitStructure.SPI_FirstBit = SPI_FirstBit_MSB;
  SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CRCPolynomial = 7;
  SPI_InitStructure.SPI_Mode = SPI_Mode_Master;

  /* Enable SPI1  */
  SPI_SSOutputCmd(SPI1, ENABLE);
  SPI_Cmd(SPI1, ENABLE);

  /* Configure GPIO PIN for Lis Chip select */
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_3;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  /* Deselect : Chip Select high */
  GPIO_SetBits(GPIOE, GPIO_Pin_3); 
}
```

Upper code works fine, but the problem is that always when I try to read motion sensor, i get 0xFF or in another words 255. I read data by sending dummy text and then read data. 

**I have been also given an advice to set Slave Select pin (SS) to zero, but I don't know how to do that.
Does anybody know?**

Comment: You actually already have the appropriate function (SPI_SSOutputCmd) to set/clear the slave select line in your example above.

Comment: So SPI_SSOutputCmd is used for setting Slave select pin if I understand you correctly. So why is it not working when I already set it to ENABLE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hazard a guess - typically with SPI, SS is driven low (enable) at the start of each write/read then driven high (disable) at the end of each write/read to indicate end of transmission.  Without pulling out the board, that's what I'd bet on.

If that's not it - ST is pretty good at providing examples.   The [source code](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM116/SC959/SS1532/PF252419) on their product page includes an example using their MEMs accelerometer (Utilities/STM32F4-Discovery/stm32f4_discovery_lis302dl.c/.h).